# Transferring GeoTIFFs from GCS to GEE. Error: Total area of overlap between input files is too large

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, google-cloud

I am trying to transfer a batch of images from a bucket in Google Cloud Storage to Earth Engine asset. It is a time series for the same region over 30 years (~15000 images). The problem is that every time I ingest more than one image, I get the following error:

> Total area of overlap between input files is too large: 1.00e+00 of the total mosaic area. This overlap may not exceed 5.00e-01.  (Error code: 3)

I have already used the codes from [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/image_manifest), [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/command_line#upload), and [here](https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/python/examples/ipynb/Uploading_image_tiles_as_a_single_asset_using_a_manifest.ipynb) and it used to work, at least last year when I created my first bucket and transferred the data to a different account and asset.  How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you include multiple files in an upload, they are mosaiced together, which is almost certainly not what you meant to do with a time series.  Instead, you should upload each file separately, into a (pre-created) collection.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are totally right. Something so simple but totally key. Thanks again!